# What is the proper way to use string return value for Bison?

Tags: c, string, parsing, flex3, bison

What is the proper way to get the resulting string from the one or more tokens that make up the rule that Bison has found?

```
timer:
    TILDE amount  {
        printf("Timer: Amount:%s\n",$2 );
        $$ = $2;
      }

  | TILDE WORD amount { 
        printf("Timer: %s Amount:%s\n",$2, $3 );
        // make timer string
        $$ = malloc(strlen($2) + strlen($3) + 10);
        sprintf($$, "%s %s", $2, $3);
        free($2);
        free($3);
      }

  | TILDE MULTIWORD amount  { 
        printf("Timer: %s Amount:%s\n",$2, $3 );
        // make timer string
        $$ = malloc(strlen($2) + strlen($3) + 10);
        sprintf($$, "%s %s", $2, $3);
        free($2);
      }
  ;
```

time, amount, and WORD are all type string, so is MULTIWORD.

For example, if the first rule matches, meaning there is a TILDE "~" and an amount, usually a number like "3" in string format, what is the best way to get the result value, ie the 'timer' to have a value of just the amount?

If the second rule were to match, how would I go about adding WORD and amount into one string and putting them in the $$ value.
I couldn't find anything in the Bison documentation about this.

Edit: Forgot to mention the problem. The string that is printed out has more than just what I wanted to be passed on. For example, with an amount defined by:

```
amount:
    // an empty amount - for one word timers
    LCURL RCURL {
      $$ = malloc(5);
      $$[0] = ' ';
      $$[1] = '\0';
    }

  | LCURL NUMBER RCURL  { 
      // get string for amount
      $$ = malloc(100);
      sprintf($$, "%.3lf", $2);
    }

  | LCURL NUMBER UNIT RCURL { 
      // get string for amount
      // remove % from unit 
      $$ = malloc(100 + strlen($3) + 5);
      sprintf($$, "%.3lf %s", $2, $3); 
    }

  | LCURL WORD RCURL  {
      $$ = $2;
    }

  | LCURL WORD UNIT RCURL {
      $$ = malloc(strlen($2) + strlen($3) + 5);
      sprintf($$, "%s%s", $2, $3);
    }

  | LCURL MULTIWORD RCURL {
      $$ = $2;
    }

  | LCURL MULTIWORD UNIT RCURL {
      $$ = malloc(strlen($2) + strlen($3) + 5);
      sprintf($$, "%s%s", $2, $3);
    }
  ;
```

When I put $2 in the string it will also include the RCURL behind it. This leads to lots of random strings and incorrect parsing.

The full lexer file:

```
%{
  #include "Cooklang.tab.h"
  #include <stdlib.h>
  void showError();

%}


SYMB_CHAR             "$"|"="|"+"|"-"|"_"|"*"|"`"
PUNC_CHAR             "!"|"?"|","|"."|"/"|"&"|"("|")"|":"
NEW_LINE              "\n"
WHITE_SPACE           " "|"\t"
ALPHA_CHAR            [a-zA-Z]
COOKLANG_CHAR         ">"|"|"|"~"|"@"|"#"|":"|"{"|"}"|"%"



ZERO                  "0" 
NON_ZERO_DIGIT        [0-9]


DIGIT                 ({ZERO}|{NON_ZERO_DIGIT}){WHITE_SPACE}*
INTEGER               ({ZERO}|({NON_ZERO_DIGIT}{DIGIT}*)){WHITE_SPACE}*
DECIMAL               {INTEGER}"."{INTEGER}{WHITE_SPACE}*
FRACTIONAL            {INTEGER}{WHITE_SPACE}*"/"{WHITE_SPACE}*{INTEGER}{WHITE_SPACE}*


WORD                  ({ALPHA_CHAR}|{DIGIT}|{SYMB_CHAR})+{WHITE_SPACE}*

HWORD                 "#"{WORD}
ATWORD                "@"{WORD}

MULTIWORD             {WORD}{2,}


UNIT                  "%"{WHITE_SPACE}*({MULTIWORD}*|{PUNC_CHAR}*)?



%%

[ \t]

"{"                   {return LCURL;}
"}"                   {return RCURL;}
"~"                   {return TILDE;}

{ATWORD}              { yytext++;
                        yylval.string = yytext;
                        return ATWORD;
}

{HWORD}               { yytext++;
                        yylval.string = yytext;
                        return HWORD;
                      }

                      
{UNIT}                { yytext++;
                        yylval.string = yytext;
                        return UNIT;}

{DIGIT}               { yylval.number = strtod(yytext, NULL); return NUMBER;}
{INTEGER}             { yylval.number = strtod(yytext, NULL); return NUMBER;}
{DECIMAL}             { yylval.number = strtod(yytext, NULL); return NUMBER;}
{FRACTIONAL}          { char * tok = strtok(yytext, "/");

                        double first = strtod(tok, NULL);

                        tok = strtok(NULL, "/");

                        double second = strtod(tok, NULL);

                        double final = first/second;

                        yylval.number = final;

                        return NUMBER;}

{WORD}                { yylval.string = yytext;
                        return WORD;
                      }
{MULTIWORD}           { yylval.string = yytext;
                        return MULTIWORD;
                      }



{PUNC_CHAR}           { yylval.character = yytext[0];
                        printf("char: |%c|", yytext[0]);
                        return PUNC_CHAR; }

{NEW_LINE}            {return NL;}




%%

int main( int argc, char ** argv ){
  ++argv;
  --argc;

  if( argc > 0 ){
    yyin = fopen(argv[0], "r");
  } else {
    yyin  = stdin;
  }

  yyparse();

  yylex();
  
  printf("\n");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the way you did it?

Comment: For readability and maintainability I would avoid using `$<number>`. E.g. instead of `printf("Timer: Amount:%s\n",$2 );` you can write `printf("Timer: Amount:%s\n",$amount );`. (There is no such situation in the example but if a token repeats in a rule, you can assign an alias to it so you are free to ditch the numbers everywhere.)

Comment: Bison can also generate C++. I don't know you project but in case it is an option, I'd consider using C++. That way, you would have `std::string` which would allow you to avoid all this manual memory management.

Comment: I've noticed, you've not calling `free($3);` (or `free($amount);`) in the 3rd rule. Is this by design or is it a mistake? It would help if we can see how you create the values in your lexer.

Comment: @rici I edited the question to clarify my question

Comment: @NO_NAME Its just a mistake.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are not copying the text inside tour lexer. Please include your lex code to verify.

Comment: @rici I added the lexer file.

Comment: Ok, provided the usual answer. There are many duplicates; also, see the [Bison manual FAQ section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Strings-are-Destroyed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lexer action is incorrect:

```
yylval.string = yytext;  /* NEVER do this */
```

`yytext` is a pointer to a temporary storage buffer owned by the lexer. It's contents are only valid until the next call to the lexer; after that, the pointer may no longer be valid (if the buffer was reallocated) or the contents will have changed.

So you **must** copy the string pointed to by `yytext` if you need it to outlast the lexer action (which you certainly need if you want to pass the string to a parser).

You can just use `yylval.string = strdup(yytext)` if you have `strdup` (or include an implementation), or you can dynamically allocate the storage yourself; if you choose the latter solution, recall that `yyleng` contains the length of the text so there is no need for `strlen`:

```
    /* +1 for the null terminator */
yylval.string = malloc(yyleng + 1);  
    /* should check for allocation failure */
memcpy(yylval.string, yytext, yyleng + 1);
```

Don't forget to `free()` the copy when you no longer need it.